# Copy files to different folder without sudo access

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jenkins

I am trying to copy files/directories from one user to another user in a same machine via jenkins.

Suppose there is one file abc.txt in a directory(say /tmp/dist) where user1 has sudo access. I need to copy that file to the  directory of (/opt/user2/temp) via jenkins.

I executed these commands in interactive shells after logging in to the server.

```
sudo -u user2 -s cp /tmp/dist/* /opt/user2/temp
```

This asks for password prompt and abruptly comes out of terminal and terminates the job.

I also checked if i can remove password prompt by adding password details in /etc/sudoers but to no avail.

```
sudo visudo
```

I also tried scp to the destination folder directly but that also was not fruitful.

Tried ssh as well

```
ssh -t user2@hostname 'sudo -u user2 -s cp /tmp/dist/* user2@hostname:/opt/user2/temp'
```

edit 1:
Tried changing the owner of the group to the destination folder but it asks for password prompt again.

```
sudo chown -R user2 /tmp/dist
```

I expect directory copy from to another folder provided it doesnt asks for password prompt.
Also,I don t have access or can modify /etc/sudoers.

Comment: You have not mentioned the actual filesystem directory permissions or the groups of the users. Can you adjust the perms of the dirs outside of Jenkins.

Comment: I don't have access to change parameters outside of jenkins

Comment: Can you chmod rather chown?